# Python: Create Dataframes with different names in Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I currently have a list of languages:

`languages_list =['EN', 'DE', 'FR']`

And a different CSV file for each language.

I would need to create a loop, where for each language I create a new dataframe by uploading the specific CSV file:

```
for language in languages_list:
tables_ + str{language} = pd.read_csv(language + ".csv", header = 0, encoding = "latin1")
```

The desired output should be 3x dataframe in this case:

1. tables_EN, containing the EN csv
2. tables_FR, containing the FR csv
3. tables_DE, containing the DE csv

Is it possible to obtain an output as described?

Comment: Edited my question, sorry for not being clear enough

Answer (score 3):

I think better is create `dictionary of DataFrames` like:

```
tables={x: pd.read_csv(x + ".csv", header = 0, encoding = "latin1") for x in languages_list}

print (tables['EN'])
```

Comment: The dictionary approach is the way to go. Creating globals like that is pretty bad practice and completely avoidable in this case. Using the dictionary approach will also make looping over the 3 tables easier in the rest of your script.

Comment: Ok thank you to both! I am new to python so I will try to build my script following your advice and using a dict. Will learn something on the way for sure!

Comment: @Joost - Yes, you are right, so removed second solution.